# Spring auto configuration tries to set some bean values from application.properties while I just want to use that informations somewhere else?

Tags: spring-boot

So I use keycloak for my application and I have some values in `application.properties` like:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url            = http://10.10.10.10:1010/auth
keycloak.resource                   = test-client
keycloak.credentials.secret         = <very-big-secret>
keycloak.realm                      = test-realm
```

Spring configure the keycloak connection using these data, but I also use them in my code so I have a config like this:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keycloak")
public class KeycloakConfig {
    private String authServerUrl;
    private String realm;
    private String resource;
    private Credentials credentials;
}
```

I have an admin user in keycloak and I want it's credentials in the application.properties like this:

```
keycloak.admin.username=admin.admin 
keycloak.admin.password=changeit
```

So I tried to change my config class to this:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keycloak")
public class KeycloakConfig {
    private String authServerUrl;
    private String realm;
    private String resource;
    private Credentials credentials;
    private Admin admin;
}

@Data
public class Admin {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

But when I try to run the application like this, I think the spring tries to set the values for keycloak (the .admin part) and it does not start:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@1cd5e41 type = org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties(ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, prefix=keycloak, value=keycloak)]] failed:

    Property: keycloak.admin.password
    Value: changeit
    Origin: "keycloak.admin.password" from property source "applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [keycloak.admin.password,keycloak.admin.username] were left unbound.
    Property: keycloak.admin.username
    Value: admin.admin
    Origin: "keycloak.admin.username" from property source "applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [keycloak.admin.password,keycloak.admin.username] were left unbound.

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Is it possible to have the `.admin` part under `keycloak` or I have to make a new class for example:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-keycloak")
public class MyKeycloakConfig {
    private Admin admin;
}
```

And:

```
my-keycloak.admin.username=admin.admin 
my-keycloak.admin.password=changeit
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with KeyCloak, but you can inject the bean that initialized by KeyCloak that reads the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak reads values from application properties using KeycloakSpringBootProperties. Looks like there are no such values as username or password. Probably Keycloak doesn't require those values to work properly.

So you need to specify the properties separately from Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you cannot customize `keycloak.*` "domain" in spring-boot (loaded) properties!
   Proof: [KeycloakSpringBootProperties](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/spring-boot-adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springboot/KeycloakSpringBootProperties.java), which says:

   ```
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keycloak", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
   ```

---

2. So it is definitely the second approach!
   By defining (in application.properties):

   ```
   my-keycloak.admin.username=admin.admin 
   my-keycloak.admin.password=changeit
   ```

   a) ... You can just go for:

   ```
   @Value("${my-keycloak.admin.xxx}")
   private String myKeacloakXXX;
   ```

   b) Or as described by [Typesafe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) (and implemented by [1] for `prefix="keycloak"`):

   - You (just) have to introduce a "pojo" like (depicting your properties structure(type safe)):

     ```
     @ConfigurationProperties("my-keycloak.admin") 
     public class MyKeykloakProperties {
       private String username, password; // getter, setter/lombok
     }
     ```

     You can have also more structure with `"my-keykloak"` (prefix, and nesting classes/properties, see [exmaple/doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding))
   - To enable them:

     ```
     @Configuration
     // Or:
     @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyKeykloakProperties.class)

     // OR:
     //@ConfigurationPropertiesScan({ "com.example.app", "com.example.another" }) 
     public class MyKeycloakConfig { ...
     ```

     see also [Enabling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types).
   - Then you can "wire" them as you see fit (also in the above config class):

     ```
     @Autowired
     private MyKeykloakProperties properties;
     ```

   As a decision help, please refer to: [`@Value` vs type safe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation).

Cheers